# When I run flutter doctor --android-licenses in VS code, it said Java Runtime version not compatible

Tags: java, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-sdk-tools

When I run command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, it shows the following error. I have already installed JDK 21 and Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest). JDK also included in the path as well. Also another suggestion from stackoverflow recommend to install older version of command-line tools. Which I did as well. Any suggestion for this?

```
??: ?????? com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli ??? LinkageError
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Comment: You can temporarily [set the Java path to a lower version](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) to accept the licenses, and go back to 21 after that

Comment: Thanks @DhafinRayhan. Which version do you recommend? I've downloaded JDK 8, gonna try now.

Comment: Yes, I think JDK 8 should work.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan unfortunately its still not working. What's worse I somehow cannot reverse back to JDK 21. This is my version now.

```java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
```

Comment: If you follow [the instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) correctly it should do no harm. Make sure you have changed back the environment variable path, and close the current terminal for the changes to take effect

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I have followed the instructions. What I have done is:
1. Create a new variable called JAVA_HOME, path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
2. Edit PATH and create new: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
3. Saved everything, even when I typed java -version in VS Code terminal it showed java version 1.8.0_202-b08.

But when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses its still the same.

Comment: Upgrade the JDK to a version that supports class file version 61.0, install an older version of the Android SDK command line tool that is compatible with the current JRE, verify that the environment variables are set correctly, and follow the steps recommended by Flutter Doctor.

Comment: @JialeDu I have already tried Java 21 that is the latest, and Java 17 as well which also supports class file version 61.0. I have also installed the latest Android SDK and version 8. Still not working. I have no clue.